Is there a canonical list of travel industry payment card codes (VI, MC, AX, etc...)?
For hotel bookings, hotels provide a list of accepted payment cards to the GDS under GuaranteesAccepted.  Common ones are "AX" - American Express, "VI" - Visa, etc.
I want to make sure our application has covered all the bases.  Does anyone know of an industry-standard list of these two-character payment card codes?
I've checked the OTA docs as well as developer docs for Sabre and Amadeus -- no dice.  I've also run hotel searches and tried to aggregate the codes I've found from those responses, but it seems like there should be a complete list somewhere.  Or is this something that's purely a convention?

The codes aren't provided by hotels. There can't be a standard for codes that represent companies or rather, payment schemes. New ones get created all the time. Hotels are small enough that they may not be able to handle all payment schemes. Airlines aren't.

Besides, it's you that knows what schemes are allowed. It's not a single hotel you're asking about here. You're talking about CC-to-carrier payments, which are sent directly to the airline for processing. You can't sell tickets from an airline unless your agency has a specific agreement with this, at which point they tell you what they accept. It's up to you (the OTA) to not send invalid schemes during booking. Either you only display the common schemes to users, or you handle the payment for the customer yourself and book the flights as CAsh

Besides, even if the two big GDSs provide an API, you can't call it on every booking because that costs and adds delays and burns CPU. Which, when you sell thousands of tickets per day, can be expensive. All that to get information you already have, that can only change through contracts with the airline

run hotel searches airlines aren't hotels. The scale doesn't even come close. Hotels are a lot, tiny (in terms of transactions), and the actual data you get isn't even provided by them. They update their lookup info in Booking.com's or  GDS systems. Airlines are fewer but many times larger, and process their own information.
